# Convert Excel with internal links to pdf

Tags: excel, pdf

I am trying to convert an excel with internal links(i.e. links to different places within that same excel) to a pdf. I have gone through the several posts available online in this regard and couldn't seem to find any proper solution for such a conversion. The solutions provided mostly works for the external hyperlinks and not the internal one's. Is it even possible to do so? Is there any software that might be able to achieve this functionality?

Basically, I am looking to migrate whole of the excel workbook to one single pdf such that every link between different worksheets in that workbook still works. For example, if I have provided a link in worksheet one that points to a named section in worksheet two, I would like this relation to be maintained within pdf as well. So, in the resulting pdf when I click on the link, it should take me to that named section location in the pdf.

Comment: I'd convert to Word http://smallbusiness.chron.com/convert-excel-sheets-word-40305.html then export to pdf. Both steps can be automated via VBA.

Comment: The solution that I am looking for is a bit different. The solution above is useful if the users are ready to open the excel file whenever they click on the link in the word file. Secondly, the user would need to copy every worksheet separately. I have modified the description to state exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to keep internal and external links that works:

1. Install Office 2013/2016
2. Install Adobe Acrobat PRO 11 (for Office 2013) or Adobe Acrobat DC (for Office 2016)
3. Open Excel file and use "**Save as Adobe PDF**" entry from the File menu. Screenshot below. This pops up another dialog where you select sheets for saving.
   Main idea is to have Adobe Add-in active inside the Office ribbon and File dialog.

Works like a charm! Finally!

[image: Saving Excel to PDF and preserving the links]

Comment: One caveat: if you use the "shrink to page" function in Excel, this seems to create unusual sized pages in our workflow.  Microsoft describes the problem in [this knowledgebase article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2519799/when-exporting-an-excel-spreadsheet-as-a-pdf-file-the-page-dimensions), "When Exporting an Excel Spreadsheet as a PDF File, the page dimensions may change."