# Excel Hyperlinks to Excel documents not working

Tags: excel, hyperlink

We have a excel document that contains a ton of Hyperlinks to other Excel Documents & File Paths all located on our network. All of a sudden the Hyperlinks to the Excel Documents have broken, Excel will state the error below;

> Some files can contain viruses or otherwise be harmful to your computer. It is important to be certain that this file is from a trustworthy source.
>
> Would you like to open this file? OK/Cancel

We click OK and nothing will happen. Opening file paths is still working fine and I've created another Excel document which has links to a PDF, a File Path, a Word Doc & an Excel Doc. Still only the Excel that isn't working.

I have followed several articles online that suggest how to disable the warning message,below is a well detailed article for 2007/2010 but we had tried to adapt it for 2013/6. Nothing I have tried is working, does anyone on Stack have any suggestions?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/925757/how-to-enable-or-disable-hyperlink-warning-messages-in-2007-office-pro

We are using Office 2013/6 Standard/Professional.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Many thanks,

Sean

Comment: Check this solution with Excel 2013 + adobe 11 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176645/convert-excel-with-internal-links-to-pdf

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you copy the excel file to different location:
You can do test: place hyperlink into 1 cell save it, and then copy the file to another location: you can see that hyperlink of your copied excel file would not work.
However when you choose the same file to "Save As": the hyperlink of the saved file in different location will work.

For excel internal hyperlinks (hyperlinks to other worksheet cells) similar thing happens when you rename the file: hyperlinks won't work, but they will work if you choose to "Save As".

This means, **the solution** to this problem would be: copy the excel file to it's original location and name it with the original name (when hyperlinks were working). In this case hyperlinks will work. Then if you need to move or rename the file: open the file from original location and select "Save AS" anywhere you would like to save, in this case hyperlinks of your saved file would work.

**Conclusion**: relative references to the Excel file in hyperlinks are not automatically updated when externally file is moved or renamed.

Answer (score 0):

So we managed to find out what was the cause of this problem.

Microsoft are currently working on fixing this as stated in the article below, but as a quick fix you simply need to remove Windows Update KB4011051.

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Hyperlinks-to-another-Excel-workbook-no-longer-work-after-updating-to-the-August-1-2017-update-KB-4011051-dfe0aa5c-a2ba-41b8-923a-fe0e4556f936

Thanks for the assistance,

Sean